# map.erase( map.end() )?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

Consider:

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map< int, int > m;
    m[ 0 ] = 0;
    m[ 1 ] = 1;

    m.erase( 0 );  // ok
    m.erase( 2 );  // no-op
    m.erase( m.find( 2 ) );  // boom!
}
```

(OK, so the title talks abouting erasing an end() iterator, but find will return end() for a non-existent key.)

Why is erasing a non-existent key OK, yet erasing end() blows up. I couldn't see any explicit mention of this in the standard?

I've tried this on VS2005 (throws an exception in debug configuration) and GCC 4.0.1 (100% CPU). Is it implementation dependent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For `erase(key)`, the standard says that all elements with value key are removed. There may of course be no such values.

For `erase(it)` (where `it` is a `std::map::iterator`), the standard says that the element pointed to by it is removed - unfortunately, if it is `end()` it does not point to a valid element and you are off in **undefined behaviour** land, as you would be if you used `end()` for any other map operation. See section 23.1.2 for more details.

Comment: To clarify: there are different overloads of erase(), and the iterator version requires a valid element.

Comment: erase(it) is equivalent to erase(it, ++iterator(it)), which helps me to see that erase(it) is invalid with it=map.end(). You would need another iterator after .end().

Comment: Can anyone provide a link to the standard?

Comment: The final Standards documents are not available on-line, but you can see an early draft here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/

Comment: It's a bit late, but it still can help peoples : Here you have the doc http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase

Answer (score 19):

`end()` is not an interator into the map. It's effectively 'one past the end' of the map.

The 'iterator' version wants an iterator to something in the map.
The 'key' version of erase does the lookup and protects itself against key not found, the iterator version assumes you aren't trying to break stuff.

Comment: "assumes you aren't trying to break stuff"... I understand, I was hoping erase(it) would do a simple check that it != end()

Comment: Not an unreasonable thought, it's just that many parts of the STL containers don't want the overhead of such checks. In cases like erase, the iterator is probably been used for something else before you wanted to erase the entry, so they leave out the check for end - because you probably already did it. In the key case, it's more likely that the caller doesn't know if the key is in the map or not, so they do the check.

Comment: Addition to the previous comment, just for better understanding the map: it is a binary search tree (standard requires it to be ordered; most commonly implemented as red-black tree), and to erase a key, one first needs to find it anyway, whether it exists or not - so one is hangling down the tree (making erase(key) an O(log n) operation) anyway, and accepting a non-existent key does not imply any extra work (as would do the check in erase(it)), so it is logical to accept it as input.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the example given in a previous post...

```
MapType::iterator it = the_map.find ("new_key");

// Does not exist.
if (it == the_map.end()) {
  the_map.insert (std::make_pair ("new_key", 10));
}
```

which does two tree traversals, use...

```
pair<MapType::iterator, bool> rc = the_map.insert(make_pair("new_key", 0));
if (rc.second)
    rc.first.second = 10;
```

That way you do one tree traversal and you have the iterator ready to roll for other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of how I use the STL map with iterators while removing. I also do the same thing when performing an insert. Personally I like using typedef to specifically define the map, but the choice is yours.

```
typedef std::map... MapType;

MapType the_map;

MapType::iterator it = the_map.find ("key");
if (it != the_map.end()) {
  // Do something productive.
  the_map.erase (it);
}

MapType::iterator it = the_map.find ("new_key");

// Does not exist.
if (it == the_map.end()) {
  the_map.insert (std::make_pair ("new_key", 10));
}
```

Hope this helps!