# I read map.erase(map.end()); deletes the last element of the map.But what's the last element? Is it based in the insertion order of elements?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am beginner.Let suppose I create

```
 map<int, node*> mp;
```

where a node is

```
struct node{
node *previous;
int key; // I have no idea why there is a key variable in this node
int value;
node *next
};
```

So the map has int key, points to the node of a doubly linked list.

Let suppose I inserted the following elements in the order.

```
<key,(let corresponding node.value element be)>  
<5, 1>
<10,2>
<8, 3>
```

So the doubly linked list looks like:

```
1<->2<->3
```

Now if I want to insert a new node in between existing nodes with node values 2,3. And so I created a new map element.

```
<key,(let corresponding node.value element be)>  
<7, 4>
```

And the (newly adjusted) doubly linked list looks like:(as per my requirement)

```
1<->2<->4<->3
```

Which element will mp.erase(mp.end()); delete,and why?

I wrote a sample program in which map element <8,3> is deleted.Why does this happen?

FYI: I am working for the LRUcache code.

Comment: `map.erase(map.end());` is an error; end-iterators represent a singular state (e.g. past-the-end or a special state).  Maps don't preserve the insertion order; if you delete the last element of a map then it will be the one with the largest sort key

Comment: @M.M but it works very much fine for me.It is deleting an element

Comment: About the sort order: [std::map, how to sort by value, then by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842035/stdmap-how-to-sort-by-value-then-by-key)

Comment: @t.niese but according to sorted order of keys <10,2> is the last element, the why does the command delete <8,3> in my program.

Comment: As @M.M said `map.erase(map.end());` is an _error_  and results in an undefined behaviour: [map.erase( map.end() )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952888/map-erase-map-end) or [std::map::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) `[...]The iterator pos must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the end() iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for pos.[...]`

Comment: @sql_dummy see [What is undefined behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939)

Comment: *"I read map.erase(map.end()); deletes the last element of the map"*. That is incorrect. Where did you read it?

Comment: @M.M thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, map.end():

> Returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the map
>   container.

past-the-end element is a virtual element (that is, it actually doesn't exist). It represents the element just after the last valid element of the map.

If you ask, *why a virtual element? Shouldn't `map.end()` actually mean the last element present?*

This is because most of the operations that involve the C++11 containers like `map`, `set`, `vector` etc. specify their operations as `[  )` which means that whenever you supply a range to any operation, that range is interpreted as: **First element included, last element not**.

Example, `[2,5)` means operation has to be performed on 2,3,4.

Second, when you call  `mp.erase(element)`, this `element` has to be a valid and dereferencable element. But you are specifying `map.end()` to it.

`mp.erase(mp.end())` must not work.

Coming back to your question, TL;DR:

**Map doesn't keep a record of insertion order**.

So deleting from the end means deleting the last element present in the map, sorted by the key.

Answer (score 2):

```
map<int, node*> mp;
mp.insert(make_pair(5, nullptr));
mp.insert(make_pair(10, nullptr));
mp.insert(make_pair(8, nullptr));
```

`std::map` is internally sorted by it's key, by default in ascending order, using `std::less<Key>`. Therefore, the second value, which could be anything, does not matter.

```
mp.erase(--mp.end());
// or
mp.erase(std::prev(mp.end(), 1));
```

Should always the delete the pair with the key "`10`", not the one with the key "8" as you may think.